# ReactJS - How to remove an item from an array in a functional component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list

I am trying to create a simple shopping cart using ReactJS and I figured a potential way out but whenever I click on the remove button I've set it doesn't really remove the items from the cart..
So those are my state managers right here:

```
let[product, setProduct] = useState([])
//The function bellow is what I use to render the products to the user
const[item] = useState([{
        name: 'Burger',
        image: '/static/media/Burger.bcd6f0a3.png',
        id: 0,
        price: 16.00
    },
    {
        name: 'Pizza',
        image: '/static/media/Pizza.07b5b3c1.png',
        id: 1,
        price: 20.00
    }])
```

and I have a function that adds the objects in item to the product array, then I have a function that is supposed to remove them that looks like this:

```
    const removeItem=(idx)=>
{
    // let newProduct = product.splice(idx,1)
    // setProduct([product,newProduct])
    // $('.showItems').text(product.length)
    // product[idx]=[]
    product.splice(idx,1)

    if(product.length<=0)
    {
        $('.yourCart').hide()
    }
}
```

This function is called from here:

```
                    {product.map((item, idx)=>
                <div className='yourCart' key={idx}>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <div>
                        <img src ={item.image}></img>
                        <h3 className='burgerTitle'>{item.name}</h3>
                        <h4><strong>$ {item.price}.00</strong></h4>
                        <Button variant='danger' onClick={()=>removeItem(idx)}>Remove</Button>
                    </div>
                    <br></br>
              </div>)}
```

The problem is that I've tried to use splice, setState, I tried to even clear the entire array and add the elements that are left after applying the filter function to it but it was all to no avail.
How can I make it so that when I click on the remove button it removes the specific item from the array??

Comment: you are mutating state by calling `splice` directly on it. If this is the route you want to take you can pass a callback to setState `setProduct(prevProduct => prevProduct.splice())`

Comment: @pilchard hey thanks for the quick reply !! at first glance it seems to be working, but whenever I add more than one product and click remove on, say the second or the third product, it removes the entire list of products. Why is that?

Comment: you need to still pass your `(idx, 1)` to splice, but the answer using `id` instead is a more robust solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the mutation method `setProduct` provided from the useState hook to mutate `product` state.

```
const removeItem = (id) => {
    const index = product.findIndex(prod => prod.id === id); //use id instead of index
    if (index > -1) { //make sure you found it
     setProduct(prevState => prevState.splice(index, 1));
    }   
}
```

usage

```
<Button variant='danger' onClick={()=>removeItem(item.id)}>Remove</Button>
```

as a side note:

Consider using definite id values when working with items in an array, instead of index in array. the index of items can change. Use the item.id for a key instead of the index when mapping. Consider using [guids](https://www.guidgenerator.com/#:%7E:text=GUID%20(or%20UUID)%20is%20an,UUID%20is%20used%20everywhere%20else.) as identification.

```
{product.map((item, idx)=>
  <div className='yourCart' key={`cartItem_${item.id}`}> //<-- here
      <hr></hr>
      <div>
          <img src ={item.image}></img>
          <h3 className='burgerTitle'>{item.name}</h3>
          <h4><strong>$ {item.price}.00</strong></h4>
          <Button variant='danger' onClick={()=>removeItem(item.id)}>Remove</Button>
      </div>
      <br></br>
</div>)}
```

Comment: In the meantime, in const index = product.findIndex(prod => prod.id === id); how does the prod.id get it's value?

Comment: I assume you are pushing items from `item` state into `product` as you add them to your cart. each `item` object has an id property, so then your product items would too. findIndex will call the function inside the brackets (prod => prod.id === id) for every item in the array. see more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp#:~:text=The%20findIndex()%20method%20executes,Otherwise%20it%20returns%20%2D1)

Comment: Got it ! Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

You can define `removeItem` as a `function`, which gets an `id` (instead of an index, since that's safer) and `setProduct` to the subset which should remain. This could be achieved in many ways, in this specific example I use [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the subset of `product` whose elements differ in their `id` from the one that is to be removed and set the result as the new value of `product`.

```
removeItem = (id) => {
  setProduct(product.filter((i)=>(i.id !== id)))
 
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. A code-only answer like this one is of limited value and would benefit from an explanation of the problem/solution, the assumptions that you're making, etc.. As an example - if you're choosing not to use `splice`, you could elaborate why.

Comment: I like the answer, straight to the point!